# How to properly access the exact fields validated with VeeValidate v3 observer (validateWithInfo)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

Is it possible to find out what exact field/child/node/DOM element the `VeeValidate v3` [ValidationProvider](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/api/validation-provider.html) watches/listens to?

Currently, I am sorry, but updating to wonderful [VeeValidate v4](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/) is not possible in this project.

The main reason is to locate what field corresponds to what [Vue VNode](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#VNode-Interface) or DOM Node/Element after executing ValidationObserver's [validateWithInfo](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/blob/v3/src/components/Observer.ts#L174) which returns a Promise resolving to an object with [ObserverField](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/blob/v3/src/components/Observer.ts#L25) object(s) which, in turn, contains primitive values only but is keyed matching field name each.

One of the reasons the names (i.e. `<abc name="Amazing Name Field" />`) are stated is validation messages [interpolation function](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/blob/v3/src/localize.ts#L50).

For example, it would allow to focus on that invalid non-native or native field without `name` nor `id` prop or attribute assigned in more appropriate manner without re-iterating through the whole DOM again searching for a needle.

---

Considering the [source code](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/blob/v3/src/components/common.ts#L167), it seems VeeValidate does not store actual references to non-native (i.e. Vue Component with `<input>` inside) nor native Vue node (e.g. `<input>`) found with `v-model` but sets Vue Component (i.e. [$listeners](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/d6bdff890322bc87792094a1690bcd16373cf82d/types/vue.d.ts#L55)) or Vue native (i.e. [node.data.on](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/d6bdff890322bc87792094a1690bcd16373cf82d/types/vnode.d.ts#L69)) listeners to handle on `input`, `blur`, and `change` events.

```js
export function addVNodeListener(vnode: VNode, eventName: string, handler: Function): void {
  if (vnode.componentOptions) {
    addComponentNodeListener(vnode, eventName, handler);
    return;
  }

  addNativeNodeListener(vnode, eventName, handler);
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/blob/v3/src/utils/vnode.ts#L170)

---

Currently, it's being searched manually via iterating over `provider.$children` and searching for `id` or `name` matching the field, or querying over `provider.$el` for any DOM with these same `id` or `name`. Yet, the library allows to validate fields with neither assigned and containing multiple fields inside even if it listens to a single since [v3.3.0](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/migration.html#migrating-from-3-2-x-to-3-3-0): [extractId](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/blob/v3/src/components/Provider.ts#L391), [findInputNodes](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/blob/v3/src/components/Provider.ts#L215).